# Script for deleting database, dirs, Then restore default database, dirs

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

OS: Windows Server 2012 using SQL Server 2012

I have recently taken control of a training environment, and I need a script that will perform the following:

i.   Delete the current database from SQL 2012
ii.  Delete 2x windows DIR's
iii. Restore a default state database to SQL2012
iv.  Copy 2x Windows Dirs back to the recently deleted DIR

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you a good starting point

```
DECLARE @cmd varchar(8000)
DECLARE @Copycmd varchar(8000)
DECLARE @DeleteDir varchar(256)
SET @DeleteDir = 'C:\Test\'
SET @Deletecmd = 'RMDIR ' + @DeleteDir 
SET @CopyCMD = 'xcopy "C:\1\*" "C:\2\" /i /s /e /h /T'

EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @Deletecmd
GO
USE [master]
GO
ALTER DATABASE [my_db_name] SET  SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
GO
USE [master]
GO
DROP DATABASE [my_db_name]
GO
RESTORE DATABASE my_db_name from disk='d:\backups\my_backups.bak' with file=1
GO
EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @CopyCMD
```